# Drawing Sprites in Android OpenGL efficiently?

Tags: opengl, 2d, android, sprites

I want to basically give myself some sprite drawing functions (making use of openGL) such as;

```
draw(Texture,x,y)
```

I want to do this using OpenGL-ES 2.0 on Android. Since the textures can be varying sizes, I was thinking I would save the vertices along with the textures and pass them to the shaders every draw call using "glVertexAttribPointer". Is there a better(performance) way of doing this?

I would also make use of a model matrix to translate/rotate the sprites. Is this a normal thing to do for 2d rendering?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to look at `SpriteBatch` then which basically involves deferring any actual GPU draw calls until all the drawing has been completed and ready to be flushed to the GPU bugger. This is a very common approach to draw 100s or even 1000s of sprites on a screen at once without negative implications on the frame rate. There's a lot of different ways to implement SpriteBatching so I'll leave the exact implementation in OpenGL to you, but in a lot of implementations I've seen ([MonoGame](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/blob/develop/MonoGame.Framework/Graphics/SpriteBatch.cs), [Direct X Toolkit](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/blob/master/Src/SpriteBatch.cpp)) the `Begin` function of the `SpriteBatch` will take a transform view matrix (which will translate, rotate and scale the sprites). I suggest you look at the implementations I've linked to and derive your own. MonoGame has OpenGL components which will probably be of use to you.